# choose audio file from sd card using intent without causing it to play

Tags: android

i want to choose audio file using intent but when i am trying to choose audio file then default music player start that audio ,so i don't want play audio file while pick the audio
any help is appreciated..

my code is

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

            intent.setType("audio/mp3/*");

            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code  :

```
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        File file = new File(path);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Edit: of course where file is the audio you want to play...hope it help

Comment: my problem is when tried to pick audio file then it play that audio file.so i want only path of that file

Comment: Which makes this suggestion of firing an ACTION_VIEW intent on it just about the opposite of the answer...

Comment: the path is you file path... AND NO if i understood what he said; which select a player to player his audio file...ACTION_VIEW should be use here so @ChrisStratton if you have better answer just help him  instead of criticizing my answer!!!

Comment: and please @user3098271 can you be more specific?? you want choose audio file from where ? post a bit more of your code!

Comment: What you are missing is that the goal is **not** to play the file.